# PHP refusing to extract docx as zip from Windows/Temp

Tags: php, upload, zip, extract, docx

```
$dir = "temp/docx";

    $errors = array();
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    if($zip->open($file_path) === false){
        $errors[] = 'Failed to open file';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $zip->extractTo($dir,"word/document.xml");
        $zip->close();
$files = scandir($dir);
print_r($files);
```

Ok so, basically for some reason the extraction wont work. After seeing the folders empty, I decided to do a scandir to see if they were deleting after the php finished. Nothing. $files variable outputs nothing (ofcourse apart from .. and .).

The zip is actually a docx file, and after explicitly checking for errors, php seems to think the zip_open works, but I'm not sure if this is just a false positive.

I'm wondering if this is due to the fact this is actually a docx file and I need to explicitly save it as a zip file on the server. Or perhaps because this happens straight after being uploaded and the temp file gets deleted before being able to do anything with it (which I imagine is unlikely, as other formats work fine). Perhaps neither of my assumptions are close, or there's the chance I wrote the whole thing wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php

/*Name of the document file*/
$document = 'demo.docx';

/*Directory*/
$dir = "temp/docx/";

/**Function to extract text*/
function extracttext($filename, $action) {
    //Check for extension
    $ext = end(explode('.', $filename));

    //Check if DOCX file
    if($ext == 'docx'){
        $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
    //else it's probebly an ODT file
    } else {
        $dataFile = "content.xml";    
    }

    //Create a new ZIP archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    // Open the archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
        // If successful, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            // Index found! Now read it to a string
            $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // Load XML from a string
            // Ignore errors and warnings
            $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            if($action == "save"){
                // Save xml to file
                file_put_contents($dir ."word/document.xml", $xml->saveXML());
                return "File succesfully saved.";
            } else if($action == "text"){
                // Remove XML formatting tags and return the text
                return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
            }
        }
        //Close the archive file
        $zip->close();
    }

    // In case of failure return a message
    return "File not found";
}

//Save xml file
echo extracttext($document, "save");
//Echo text from file
echo extracttext($document, "text");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. I've already got an extension check on the upload page (each separate format has its own include). Any chance you can explain to me a little in depth why my version didn't work? I don't like to just copy and paste code I like to understand it and learn. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @joopjoopjoop Well you're going to laugh rly hard when you realise it. You simply forgot to open the file before extracting it :P You're only opening it to see if you can open it xD

Comment: Now I'm getting 'file not found". The file name is saved as $file_path but I added $filename = $file_path hoping it'd work that way. Is there anything else I need to change in this to make it work?

Comment: Oh man I thought it was that when I looked over my code and saw that I was only checking the if(..=== false) lmao, that's what you mean, right?

Comment: Well I've only added $document as an example. You can simply do: echo extracttext($file_path, "save"); If $file_path is holding the document like "mydoc.docx". If it's only holding "mydoc", change it to extracttext($file_path .".docx", "save");

Comment: Can I just $document = $file_path it?

Comment: Depends. What exactly is inside $file_path ?

Comment: $file_path is C:/Windpws/Temp/[file].tmp (ie, the path of the form upload). I've planted a few echos (debug method I learned in my as3 days), and it seems to skip everything under the "if (true === $zip->open($filename))" statement, any idea why it's doing this?

Comment: Idea sure. PHP can't magicly read inside Windows tmp files. So it's unable to find the uploaded file. To be honest I always work with linux servers and I have no idea why the docx file ends up inside a tmp file in the first place. If I were you I would simply change the php.ini file and setup a temp dir inside your docroot

Comment: All files are uploaded to that folder, and no other extensions seem to have a problem with being read (I've managed to open an uploaded RTF, take out the formatting, and print it onto the page, from this folder). Also works fine with .txt. But to be fair, this was the only extension that's required an extraction from a zip file... I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you contact me on my email? You can find it on my profile. This discussion is simply getting to long for comments now. I'll give you a link to my chatserver so we can talk more easily about this through email.

Comment: You should have a reply.